# Reduce width and show scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Please see [this page](https://mu88.github.io/2020/02/07/Refactor-Dependency-Injection.html#sample): you can see the same code snippet twice: once embedded via GitHub Gist and in the second part via Jekyll's internal syntax highlighter Rouge.

I'm trying to style the second code snippet similar to the GitHub Gist. I'm making progress, but I don't know how to reduce the width of the second code snippet via CSS. It should have the same width as the surrounding blog content (like the GitHub Gist) and show a horizontal scroll bar.

How can I reduce the width of the code snippet via CSS and display a horizontal scroll bar?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the width to 100% to fill the surrounding blog content and use the `overflow-x` property to display a horizontal scroll bar.

```
.highlight {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

You can use `overflow-x: auto;` instead of `overflow-x: scroll;` to let the browser decide when to display a horizontal scrollbar, e.g. when content is overflowing.

Comment: Wow, you my CSS hero!!! Now the scroll bar gets displayed also on code snippets which wouldn't require it (e. g. [here](https://mu88.github.io/2020/02/07/Refactor-Dependency-Injection.html#sample2)). If we could solve this, I'd mark your post as the answer :)

Comment: Glad I helped. Using ```auto``` instead ```scroll``` should solve this for you.